# Block access to a website unless I have VPN enabled?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

I'm using ExpressVPN + Chrome to access cryptocurrency trading sites and I don't want to accidentally open them without the VPN enabled. Is there a way to block the site unless I have the VPN enabled? Alternatively, it'll also work if there's a Chrome extension that could remind me to check whether I've enabled my VPN whenever I try to access the site.

The ExpressVPN Chrome extension has a setting "Connect on browser launch", but it doesn't seem to work.